# Windows unable to connect to exposed to Docker port

Tags: windows, docker, containers, devops

So I have a container running with port forwarding set up. It seems that the port is listening on the local windows host, for some reason, the connection won't go through.

The command to run the docker container:

```
docker run -p 4400:4400 storybook:latest
```

Inside the container itself, I can verify the service is running on port 4400:

```
netstat -ltnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4400          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      33/node
```

```
wget http://0.0.0.0:4400
--2022-08-23 19:57:12--  http://0.0.0.0:4400/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:4400... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5866 (5.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

100%[==============================================================================>] 5,866       --.-K/s   in 0s

2022-08-23 19:57:12 (363 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [5866/5866]
```

And on the windows host, I can verify docker is listening on port 4440:

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
 TCP    [::]:4400              [::]:0                 LISTENING       20412
```

```
tasklist
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
com.docker.backend.exe       20412 Console                    1     26,540 K
```

But I can't access the service via the Windows host.

```
wget http://localhost:4400
wget : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

I even tried getting the IP address of the docker container:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
898079f335be   storybook:latest   "npx nx serve storyb…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:4400->4400/tcp, :::4400->4400/tcp   relaxed_mayer

> docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 898079f335be
172.17.0.2
```

And tried accessing the service via that IP:

```
wget http://172.17.0.2:4400
wget : Unable to connect to the remote server
```

The version of windows:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise
Version: 21H2
OS Build: 19044.1766
```

Docker information:

```
Client:
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., 2.0.0-beta.4)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 7
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 6
 Images: 22
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc version: b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 25.06GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: VFD3:RX76:D4JD:5Z6P:R2IQ:7JD4:FFQS:YDLJ:BDNW:J4UX:4U5A:GF4S
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

EDIT: I am using WSL2 as the backend.

Comment: Are you using wsl2 or hyperv?

Comment: I am using WSL2